# How to remove white space around entire webpage

Tags: html, css

I'm a CSS/HTML beginner trying to put together a webpage for a school assignment.

There's a lot of white space around my entire webpage that I'm not sure how to remove. You can see it if you try to scroll right on the page. It's especially noticeable on mobile. I'm trying to make this webpage look good on all devices, but I can't really improve the responsiveness of this design without first fixing this issue. Thank you so much in advance for your help.

[See what I'm referring to here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16iOx.jpg)

Comment: can you provide some code so that we know where you went wrong... but maybe try putting a width on you container class like `width:100vw`

Comment: Welcome to SO. You need to provide some code that reproduces the issue to be answered here. No one can help you without seeing your code.

Comment: Look into CSS Resets or Normalize. Browsers have many defaults that you need to 'normalize'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write first line css style

```
{ 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```